# how can i add a new key value to my request.data in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how can I add a new value to my **request.data**

this is my **request.data**,  structure:

```
[{'fname': 'john', 'lname': 'Doe'}]
```

how can I add the age key for example

This is my whole code :

```
def create(self, request):
    formSerializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
 #### look Down
    request.data['master'] = self.request.user.id
 #######
    if formSerializer.is_valid():
        formSerializer.save()
        objectSerializer = TeamSerializer(Team.objects.all(), many=True)
        return Response(objectSerializer.data, status = 
             status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(formSerializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is my model

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

# Create your models here.
class Team(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
```

i have two input fields ( name + comment )  so i need master field that's why

Comment: Did you really not know how to do this?  It's a dictionary inside a list.  `request.data[0]['key'] = 39`

Comment: i did it before but i would like to avoid [0]

Comment: What???  You can't "avoid" the [0].  That's just how it works.  Your dictionary is the first entry in a list.  To get to the first entry in a list, you use `[0]`.

Comment: Why do you want to edit `request.data`? It's not really intended to be mutable

Comment: because there is a value that i'm not sending in my form, ( a server side variable ) the user id

Comment: @AliceMunin can you share the code for the view/form? Maybe a ModelForm with the user as the model/instance would work?

Comment: @lain   can you double check please :)

Comment: can i do that as a default value in the model ?  it can be a good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to not need to add **mater** in `request.data`.

Try this:

```
    def create(self, request):
        formSerializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
        # request.data['master'] = self.request.user.id
        if formSerializer.is_valid():
            formSerializer.save(master = self.request.user)
            objectSerializer = TeamSerializer(Team.objects.all(), many=True)
            return Response(objectSerializer.data, status = 
                 status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(formSerializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Remove **master** from serializer's fields
and add this in `serializer`:

```
    class MYSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        username = serializers.CharField(source='master.username',read_only=True)
        
        class Meta:
            model = MY_MODEL
            fields = (OTHER_FIELDs,'username')
```

[Source Mean??](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null)

Comment: as an error "master This field is required."

Comment: @AliceMunin Remove `master` from serializer fields..

Comment: `user_name = serializers.CharField(source='master.username',read_only=True)
fields = [OTHER_FIELDs,user_name]`

Comment: if i do that ( removing master from the serializer ) it's gonna be possible if i want to get the master field also when i fetch, i mean the master field will show up when i do Team.objects.all()

Comment: please :)   what do you mean by       master.username    ?    is master a table ?

Comment: [See source mean..](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null)